# How to add markers on a mapviews from XML downloaded on the Internet?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-mapview, markers

I'm beginner in Android Development.

I'm looking for how to add markers on a map. The markers locations are downloaded (XML) trough the Internet, using AsyncTask (and progress dialog)

But I have difficulties when I'm trying to add markers on the map...

Could you give me examples ?

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<points count="1655" status="ok">
<p>
  <label>743546</label>
  <lat>48478081</lat>
  <lng>-2740572</lng>
</p>

<p>
  <label>743547</label>
  <lat>47068442</lat>
  <lng>-850537</lng>
</p>
[...1653 others...]
</point>
```

Thank you by advance,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You have to search for a good kml or xml handler, so you can get the values from the xml and add them in arrays and use them in your code..

Note: (In kml or xml handlers you deal with tags which can make reading the xml file so easy)